# Fade one background image for another on hover of link using jquery or css transition properties

Tags: jquery, css, background-image, transition, fade

Title might be a bit confusing.

I have `.main-container` div holding my entire page content.

On link hover on `#cheffing` I need to change `.main-container`'s background image from one image to another and fade between the two images.

Problem is, during the fade, I want my content inside `.main-container` to still be visible, only have the background image be effected, not the whole container.

I'm not even sure how to tackle this. Should I use just jQuery? CSS? `classToggle()`? `fadeOut()`? I'm not sure...

I'm using jQuery. Sorry if this doesn't make sense. If you need more I'll be around.

Code Pen

https://codepen.io/JDSWebService/pen/NjmrRv

HTML

```
<div class=".main-container">
  Other Misc Page Content
  <a href="#" id="cheffing">Cheffing</a>
  Other Misc Page Content
</div>
```

CSS

```
.main-container {
  height: 100vh;
  background: url("../imgs/background.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: background 1s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a working snippet for this? We can't debug what we don't see.

Comment: added some code to bring in some context

Comment: *«Title might be a bit confusing.»* I love that one... You can't animate background images since it is not in DOM. You'll have to set the image as an element with `z-index` to bring it behing the text content to be able to manipulate it using jQuery.

Comment: Could you provide an example? I have rarely used z-index, and it seems as though every time i do, my page alignment goes all haywire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't animate a background.

Here is [**an simple example**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/LyvZLP).

So, positionning an image **element** within the element you want to have a background as `absolute` with a lower `z-index` will bring it behind the rest of the content.

Then the use of `.hover()` can switch between two images URL.

---

**EDIT**
Here is a [**second example**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/YVMWOG) using 2 images instead of 2 URL on 1 image (to avoid the *the white in between*).

HTML:

```
<div class=".main-container">
  <img id="background-1" src="firstImage.jpg">
  <img id="background-2" src="secondImage.jpg">
  content...
```

CSS:

```
.main-container {
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: background 1s ease-out;
}
#background-1,#background-2{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  width:100%;
  height:500px;
}
#background-2{
  display:none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
var fadeOptions = {
  duration:600,
  easing:"linear"
};

$("#cheffing").hover(function(){
  $("#background-1").fadeOut(fadeOptions);
  $("#background-2").fadeIn(fadeOptions);
},
function(){
  $("#background-2").fadeOut(fadeOptions);
  $("#background-1").fadeIn(fadeOptions);
});
```

Comment: Did you forget the ';' at the very last line? What about the transition fade out portion of the problem?

Comment: Yes... and the fading effect you wanted... Hold on.

Comment: Any way to make it fade from one image to another without the white in between? this is what my client requested, and i'm trying to get this done right for him.

The fade to and from white is bade because the font on the page is white.

Comment: @Lokesh Gupta: sorry for the edit reject... I was editing in the mean time ;)

Comment: @LokeshGupta: You'l have to use two images for this... lol... Hold on, I'll update again.

Comment: Here it is without the white in between.

Comment: My pleasure! ;)